# wordpress make changes to post api

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

We are using wordpress for blogs (hosted via Godaddy).  I am not a wordpress developer and hence this basic question. We have the wordpress post api like blog.domainname.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. This returns a json object of most of the fields. Now i have added a custom field to be returned with this object. i have seen lot of videos and study on what changes that needs to be done especially the one here. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/

My Question is  - **Where do I make these changes?** What file do I need add these changes?  I am using WP as an admin. I installed a File Explorer plugin and I am able to see three main folders  - wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes.

Is there a particular file i need to make changes?  Based on my learning - i wrote the following snippet. not sure where to add this  :(

```
function addCustomField_register_fields() {

register_rest_field('post',
        'custom_Field_name',
        array(
            'get_callback'      =>'get_custom_field',
            'update_callback'   => null,
            'schema'        => null
        ));

    }

function get_custom_field($object, $field_name , $request) {
    return get_post('custom_field');
    }

add_action('rest_api_init', 'addCustomField_register_fields');
```

Also would appreciate if you can let me know if my method is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically theme customisations are added to the `functions.php` file in the root directory of your active theme.

As for your code, what are you trying to do? Your callback in particular doesn't look like it will work. `get_post()` loads a WordPress post by ID. `'custom_field'` isn't a valid post ID, so this will always fail.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I am custom field is a name of the new field i added. (thumbnail_image in my case). I am trying to include that property in my json object.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227506/how-to-get-custom-post-meta-using-rest-api/227515

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I Made the changes at Functions.php and it worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot. Only change i had to do was change  the return object as ~return get_post_meta($post['id'], 'thumbnail_image', true);~